# Regex No longer working (Swift 1.2)

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift, option-type

I've been using:

```
    func isValidPassword(testStr2:String) -> Bool {
        println("validate password: \(testStr2)")

        let passwordRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-:/><#]{6,30}"

        if let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegEx) {
            return passwordTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr2)
        }

        return false
    }
```

to check that string has the appropriate characters. But since the swift 1.2 Update, I get an error saying "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of an Optional type"

I've tried adding question marks. But I can't find how to fix the problem. Anyone know what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension NSPredicate {
    convenience init(format predicateFormat: String, _ args: CVarArgType...)
}
```

is not a failable initializer anymore in Swift 1.2, so you cannot
(and need not) test the return value with optional binding:

```
let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegEx)
return passwordTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr2)
```

Comment: trying it right now, I've got about 60 to change so its going to take some time :) I'll mark it as correct if that worked! Thank you Sir!